# What is the best way to share/use an excel file?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, collaboration

I am on a team of 20+ and every quarter we have to check data and make changes. Currently we use Sharepoint to share the Excel file, which will allow access to everyone with the sharepoint link.

I've noticed some issues with the current procedure: 1) This is the first time many on the team are using sharepoint (most have used a the legacy shared excel file before) so every few minutes someone will filter the data but not on "see mine" or in their own temporary view which throws off everyone else; 2) those that found using the shared file too difficult because of 1) saved a copy on their desktop, worked on it then manually saved in the sharepoint file. One person copied all their changed data that was filtered and pasted it in the sharepoint file which royally messed up the data for rows hidden by the filter. Someone also did 2) and pasted a bunch of gibberish (Ex. Interisu, Corporatiternsu, Leblanterisu) I don't understand what these things mean, maybe another language (we work in finance so should be maybe corporation or interest rate).

I have a few potential solutions including: 1) teaching everyone how to create temporary sheets; 2) personally create temporary sheets for each individual which would show only the date they need to check; 3) Use "compare and merge workbooks" where everyone would work offline and provide all the workbooks that would then be merged; 4) use the legacy shared file (also that can be very slow); 5) lock certain columns/rows from being amended like titles and put a password so no one can by accidently change information like titles; and 6) everyone works offline and then sends me their files and I manually paste the data. I am open to all suggestions as it took our team 3x as long to complete due to missed filtering and incorrectly pasting over already filled in data.

Separate question: I've noticed temp sheet view goes back to default view after a few minutes of being inactive. Is there a way to change this or extend the time? Some people don't realize their temp view went back so they filter but not only for their view.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42010458/4961700

Comment: Thanks, just wondering if there are any more potential solutions as that was over 6 years ago.

Comment: There's no easy solution. :'( . I feel your pain with the same issue (working as Data Analyst in big projects) and the only solution is that the version history in sharepoint is gold worth when the workbook get messed up. a) If it's possible the team member might have their own sheet in the workbook which is consuming data from the master sheet b) divide the work to make people only work on certain days, not fun and optimal but gives the "main user" some control to update the sheet. Workbooks tends to be a living monster.

Comment: @Wizhi version history meaning just going back like 10 minutes before the incident that messed it all up and using that one? Also yes good idea only issue is our whole team at 2 days to mine thousands of rows of data so everyone was in at all hours at once lol

Comment: Yes, something like that. Is not optimal and fun, but have saved my life a couple of time, even if a lot of manual work still needs to be done.
You can compare two workbooks with Microsoft inbuilt [Spreadsheet Compare](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-spreadsheet-compare-0e1627fd-ce14-4c33-9ab1-8ea82c6a5a7e)